# can we convert the strright hive function into oracle functionality

Tags: sql, oracle, hive, hiveql

I have hive code in my project which I need to convert it into Oracle. almost I have completed oracle code but facing issues with this STRRIGHT functionality in select statement.

```
SELECT
clmn1,
clmn2,
CASE
WHEN strright(id,3) like "%d%d%d" THEN strright(id,3)
ELSE id
END

FROM table;
```

I know that we can get the 3 right most characters with `SUBSTR(id,-3)`, but I am not sure how to compare if last three characters are digits or characters.
With this above case statement I could understand that, if ID has last 3 characters as numbers then it should display only those 3 numbers else it should return entire ID. can you please help me with this solution that how can we achieve this output with sql(oracle).

Comment: Oracle has a `REGEXP_LIKE` function that should do what you need.

Comment: Can you please tell me, how to check last 3 three digits from id with regexp_like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So - if the last three characters are digits then return those three digits, otherwise return the whole id?

Something like this:

```
with
  test_data (id) as (
    select 'ab'     from dual union all
    select '23910'  from dual union all
    select 'ab-3'   from dual union all
    select '31-309' from dual union all
    select '33'     from dual
  )
select id, case when regexp_like(id, '\d{3}$')
                then substr(id, -3) else id end as new_str
from   test_data
;

ID      NEW_STR
------  -------
ab      ab    
23910   910   
ab-3    ab-3  
31-309  309   
33      33
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simple in Oracle:

```
SELECT
clmn1,
clmn2,
CASE
WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(substr(id,-3), '^[[:digit:]]+$') THEN substr(id,-3)
ELSE id
END
FROM table;
```